# How can a model have multiple keys with the same type of models as values?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django

I'm making an application and I should make a `Model` which have 2 keys that saves models of the same type.

It's not easy to express in English so I will upload the image of the situation.

[image]

In `Food Pair Model` ( or we can call it table I think )

I want to refer `Food Model` But **I wasn't able to use ForeignKey or ManyToManyField**.

```
ERRORS:
food_test.FoodQuestion.left_food: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'FoodQuestion.left_food' clashes with reverse accessor for 'FoodQuestion.right_food'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'FoodQuestion.left_food' or 'FoodQuestion.right_food'.
food_test.FoodQuestion.right_food: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'FoodQuestion.right_food' clashes with reverse accessor for 'FoodQuestion.left_food'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'FoodQuestion.right_food' or 'FoodQuestion.left_food'.
```

I don't know what database relation to use in this case and how to make it.

What can I use for this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a `ForeignKey` from one model to another Django will dynamically create a property on the model being referenced that will return a `QuerySet` with all objects that have the foreign key to that object

For example

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    pass

class Bar(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

foo = Foo.objects.create()
bar = Bar.objects.create(foo=foo)
foo.bar_set.all()  # This will return a queryset containing foo
```

By default this property will be `<model_name_lowercase>_set`. In your case because you have 2 foreign keys from one model to the same model Django is trying to create the same property on the `Food` model for each foreign key.

To get around this issue you can specify the name of this property using [`related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name), if you set this to '+' no reverse relation will be made at all or give them unique names

```
class FoodQuestion(models.Model):
    left_food = models.ForeignKey(Food, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='+')
    left_food = models.ForeignKey(Food, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='+')
```

Answer (score 1):

You must define a unique related_name for each ForeignKey field in your FoodPair model.

```
class FoodPair(models.Model):
    first_food = models.ForeignKey(Food, related_name="first_food")
    second_food = models.ForeignKey(Food, related_name="second_food")
    what_i_buy = models.ForeignKey(Food, related_name="what_i_buy")
```

If related_name is not defined Django automatically sets it and when there is multiple ForeignKey fields pointing to the same model the names clash.